# Неверно выводится разница в дате методом DateTime php

Tags: php, datetime

Здравствуйте.

Пытаюсь вывести разницу во времени. Использую для этого такой метод, как `DateTime();` Всё замечательно, кроме одного. Когда использую даты `"2009-12-31 23:58"` и `"2010-01-01 01:57"`, то должно получиться `"-00.00.00 0:59"`. А по факту получается `"-00.00.00 59:00"`. Т.е., функция выводит разницу во времени 59 часов и 0 минут вместо 59 минут. Вот пример который я использую:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime("2009-12-31 23:58");
$datetime2 = new DateTime("2010-01-01 00:57");
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$intrl = $interval->format('%R%Y.%M.%D %I:%H');
```

Можете объяснить, почему так криво получилось?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `$intrl = $interval->format('%R%Y.%M.%D %I:%H');`

Согласно описанию форматирующей сроки

- i Минуты с ведущим нулём
- H Часы в 24-часовом формате с ведущим нулём
- I (заглавная i)   Признак летнего времени 1, если дата соответствует летнему времени, 0 в противном случае.

Собственно, что просили, то и получили

Answer (score 1):

```
$intrl = $interval->format('%R%Y.%M.%D %I:%H');
```

Расшифровываю формат: %I - минуты %H - часы. Поменяйте местами.

Comment: @anton-shchyrov в своем ответе указал на еще одну ошибку